# Сортировка по возрастанию

Tags: mysql, php, сортировка

Не знаю, может бредовый вопрос, но все-таки. Нужно отсортировать данные, которые вытаскиваются из БД по имени в порядке возрастания. Имена файлов от `1.jpg` до `2000.jpg`.
При сортировке следующим запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

данные на выходе в следующие:

`1.jpg
10.jpg
100.jpg
1000.jpg
1001.jpg
1002.jpg
1003.jpg
1006.jpg
и т.д.`

Собственно вопрос: как это дело отсортировать, чтобы на выходе данные были следующим образом:

`1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
и т.д.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY (`name`+0) ASC
```

Comment: спасибо, не знал об этой возможности

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY name+0 ASC
```

Таким образом будет сортироваться как число

Comment: баян :))))

Comment: когда я отвечал - ответа еще не было, появился потом, походу что-то с ajax-ом сайта

Comment: Читайте смайлы ;) Плюсану чтобы не обижались :)

Comment: алаверды :)