# Django. Сортировка queryset'a строк по алфавиту ['АБВ...ABC'] и возрастанию цифр ['1,2,3...10']

Tags: python, django, postgresql, сортировка, queryset

Имеется выборка объектов. У каждого объекта имеется поле "title", по которому необходимо вести сортировку. Для наглядности ниже изображу лист этих тайтлов

```
['30', '10', 'zxc', '7', 'abc', '4', '1', 'абв', 'раа']
```

В мета модели, вьюхе или шаблоне я могу применить сортировку по полю title. Например

```
 {% for obj in queryset|dictsort:'title' %}
     {{ obj.title }}
 {% endfor %}</ul>
```

В результате получим такую сортировку

```
['1', '10', '30', '4', '7', 'abc', 'zxc', 'абв', 'раа']
```

По алфавиту все ок, по цифрам нужно по возрастанию, результат необходим такой

```
['1', '4', '7', '10', '30', 'abc', 'zxc', 'абв', 'раа']
```

Как это возможно получить?

Способы, которые я видел, основаны на методе [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) и используют числовые поля, а не строки, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969348/django-ordering-numerical-value-with-order-by), если кто-то подскажет, как можно адаптировать, будет здорово

Может как-то возможно задать шаблон сортировки в мета модели или вьюхе, где прямо указать список символов?

```
***UPDATE***
```

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72456/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E?rq=1) ответ навел на решение, правда, сортировка не меняется, наверно, неправильно построил SQL-запрос к базе

```
queryset=Test.objects.extra(select={'field': 'SELECT title FROM core_page ORDER BY title ASC limit 1'})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Решение для python 2**
В python 3, при попытке сравнить строку и число, будет исключение.
Чтобы отсортировать все объекты по полю `title`, с вашим условием, можно использовать функцию `sorted`, написав обработчик для параметра `key`:

```
def key_sort(arg):
    title = arg.title
    if title.isdigit():
        res = int(title)
    else:
        res = title
    return res
```

Сортируем кверисет:

```
new_qs = sorted(YourQueryset, key=key_sort)
```

Или можно использовать `lambda` выражение

```
new_qs = sorted(
           YourQueryset, key=lambda x: int(x) if x.title.isdigit() else x.title)
```

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: @while1pass да точно, забыл добавить, что вам нужно вначале получить все поля `title`. У кверисета нету такого метода, для кверисетов используют функцию `sorted`

Comment: не пойму вашей мысли

Comment: @while1pass обновил ответ, посмотрите. Или  вам нужно выводить объект целиком отсортированный по этому полю?

Comment: дааа, я же использую выборку объектов. отдельно значения поля отсортировать не проблема

Comment: @while1pass попробуйте другое решение, обновил ответ.

Comment: Хм-хм, а правильно ли я понимаю, что в третьем питоне это уже не работает?

Comment: @andreymal а что конкретно не должно работать в третьем?

Comment: Данное решение подразумевает сравнение числа со строкой, во втором питоне числа всегда считаются меньше строк, а в третьем это выпилили

Comment: @andreymal, да точно, спасибо. Это решение будет только для второго питона